# phonegap doesn't work

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova

i have downloaded the phonegap example from its website.but it doesn't run.i can't find the reason.help me to get the solution please.when i run it shows

"The Web page at file:///andriod_asset/www/index.html could not be loaded as:
The requested file was not found.www/index.html"

Answer (score 5):

I tried with three "///" instead of four, it worked for me. Give a try
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Answer (score 3):

You've spelt android wrong here:

```
        HERE!!!
```

file://>>>>>>andriod<<<<<<_asset/www/index.html could not be loaded as: The requested file was not found.www/index.html"

Try out:

file:///android_asset/www/index.html could not be loaded as: The requested file was not found.www/index.html"

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick comment for other's getting to this same problem, who doesn't have the spelling error. My new app using PhoneGap 0.9.4 was giving this same error box. The solution was to rename phonegap.0.9.4.js and phonegap.0.9.4.jar to just phonegap.jar and phonegap.js. After that it loads up.

Answer (score 1):

You and I did the exact same thing -- flipped the i and the o in android.

Change "andriod" to "android" and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

I was using capitals for the folder WWW which was causing the same error to be thrown. I have now changed it to lowercase which works well now.