# Error in PhoneGap program "Web page not available"

Tags: android, cordova

```
package com.phonegap;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PhoneGapSampleActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("assets/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I use this code for PhoneGap application..

But it shows an error.[image]

I added index.html file in assets/www folder.
But it shows an error ...
Anyone can help me??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `file:///`. Keep in mind it's important to have the **three** slashes!

Also I think it should be android_asset and not asset.

In my app it is: `"file:///android_asset/www/index.html"`

Answer (score 0):

Simple Google search came to this :

[phonegap doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384878/phonegap-doesnt-work)

> The solution was to rename phonegap.0.9.4.js and phonegap.0.9.4.jar to just phonegap.jar and phonegap.js.